# Newer version of Telerik.Web.UI (trial version) not found

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik

A client or ours is asking us to look at his application to fix a few bugs but his application references Telerik.Web.UI. I downloaded a trial version of Telerik on my machine hoping that that would work but I get the error: Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2014.3.1024.35, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies

When I look at my version it's version 2015.1.225.40. How does one solve these types of situations, especially when you just want to help a client? I tried to do some binding redirect:

```
  <runtime>
<dependentAssembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4"  culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2014.3.1024.35" newVersion="2015.1.225.40"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

But that didn't work. Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be that the .aspx pages had a directive at the top that referenced the Telerik.Web.UI, including the version number. After I installed the trial version, and referencing it (even though it's a newer version), all I really had to do is rem out the directive at the top of the .aspx pages and the app was able to reference the assembly and the application worked. Hope this helps anyone that might go through the same path.

Comment: still, a bindingRedirect should catch that. If it does not, something may be wrong with your system. You can test if bindingRedirects work at all for you by trying them for system assemblies or create a dummy class library to test with.

Answer (score 1):

Open a ticket with Telerik and ask for access to the version you need.

That aside, a bindingRedirect should usually work, but you should target the .NET 3.5 build (2015.1.225.35) you can get from the bin35 folder in the installation.

Comment: I tried the binding redirect by targeting the .NET 3.5 build (2015.1.225.35). I replaced my referenced assembly to that version...but I still got the same error. Does the publicKeyToken change when doing this? I used the one in my code shown above. I don't have a license for Telerik so I don't think they will give me access to that version. This is to help out a client.

Comment: I think you need to have a license for that, or at least a trial :)
The publicKeyToken does not change for an assembly and it has always been 121fae78165ba3d4 so this should not be an issue.